# Java + JNA : The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java, dll, jna

I'm trying to create a dll file using visual studio and use/access it in a java project. The library seems to get loaded, but always the same exception is thrown:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'function': The specified procedure could not be found.
My C/C++ skills ar not the best so the problem could be there. I tried to edit h and cpp files, using classes, namespaces, static methods and other staff found on the web, but nothing to do. 
I have also seen other post talking about Depency Walker Tool, but it isn't able to open my dll, i also saw that the compiler add some strange suffixes to the function name, as i understood it's possible to avoid it by using "estern 'C'" in the h or cpp file, but i wasn't able.

My interface:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface SimpleDll extends Library {

    SimpleDll instance = (SimpleDll) Native.loadLibrary("SimpleDll", SimpleDll.class);

    void function();


}
```

My Main class:

```
public class Test_Dll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDll simpleDll = SimpleDll.instance;

        simpleDll.function();
    }
}
```

My h file:

```
#ifndef SIMPLEDLL
#define SIMPLEDLL

namespace simpeDll{


    static void function();


}
#endif
```

My cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "simpleDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace simpeDll;

static void function(){

}
```

Comment: Have you try declaring your function as extern "C" static void function(); outside the namespace simpleDll ?

Comment: Yes, i also tried without namespace. I guess there is a setting problem in Visual Studio, since i found out that my created library is empty. I found another tool to open DLLs, and surprisingly, there are not functions inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make sure declaring your function outside the `simpleDll` namespace.
2. Make sure to decorate it w/ `extern "C"`
3. Make sure exposing your function `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl function();` or use [module definition file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)